# Replace full content with an excerpt

Tags: content, excerpt, the-content

My theme shows full posts on the main page and I want it to show only the summary, I tried searching for the_content tag in my theme's index.php file but it is not even there!
I don't have a home.php or category.php. I tried searching my whole wordpress installation for the_content and the only places i could find it is in page.php and even when changing it there it doesn't really work.

The other places I found it in my theme formats (image.php, audio.php...) but changing it there makes the post shows the summary even when you click on it and go inside the post.

My index.php file has this :

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $format = get_post_format();  ?>

  <?php if($format == ''): ?>

    <?php get_template_part('library/functions/theme/formats/standar'); ?>


  <?php else: ?>

    <?php get_template_part('library/functions/theme/formats/'.$format); ?>

  <?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile ?>
```

Do I need to do something specific there to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decide about `the_excerpt()` or `the_content()` with a conditional: `is_singular()`.

You can use a [plugin](https://gist.github.com/2973189) and filter `the_content` depending on the current page’s type: archive or singular. But you can use it in your theme too.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 't5_replace_content_with_excerpt', 100 );

/**
 * Return excerpt if we are not on a singular post view.
 *
 * @param  string $content
 * @return string
 */
function t5_replace_content_with_excerpt( $content )
{
    if ( is_singular() )
    {
        return $content;
    }
    // remove our filter temporarily.
    // Otherwise we run into a infinite loop in wp_trim_excerpt().
    remove_filter( 'the_content', __FUNCTION__, 100 );
    $excerpt = apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', get_the_excerpt() );
    add_filter( 'the_content', __FUNCTION__, 100 );
    return $excerpt;
}
```

In your theme find the line where you are calling `the_content()`. Change it to:

```
is_singular() ? the_content() : the_excerpt();
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add that to my theme? Is it in the index file??

Comment: @user1231517 See my update.

Comment: Do i also need to add that whole if statement somewhere or just replace the_content with your update?!

Comment: Just replace the one line. My plugin code is for themes you can not edit like Twenty Eleven.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the speedy replies, i will totally try this and let you know first thing in the morning, i am in bed now posting from my phone ;)

Comment: toscho, it worked great :D been searching for something like this for days! I really appreciate it! quick thing though, my "the_content" used to say "the_content("read more"); but now when I tried your solution, it works great but how do i add the read more link?

Comment: You can still use `the_content("read more") : the_excerpt();`

Comment: I tried, no go ;(

Comment: I got it, it was in my functions.php, had to make small edits there according to this page http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More

Answer (score 0):

What theme are you working with?

This bit of code here:

```
<?php get_template_part('library/functions/theme/formats/standar'); ?>
```

Seems to suggest that your index.php is calling an template include. If you find the correct file (most likely located in that formats/standar directory) and replace the spot where the_content() appears with the the_excerpt(), you should see the summaries loading instead of the full content. This is going to modify a core theme file which is not recommended, so without knowing more about your theme and whether or not this is overridable I would say do it at your own risk.

Comment: It is a custom theme, inside the formats folder, i have standard.php, image.php, audio.php....when i open standard.php file and change the_content it does change on the front page but also when i click on the title to go inside the post, it still shows the summary only there!!!